# Why am I not able render data to screen...Can see in terminal all the data but it wont render with flatslit

Tags: react-native, react-fullstack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6ynv.png)

this is the set up... using use effect to pull all users from data to display in flat list... console.logging data from all friends and it appears in the terminal... but it will not render in flatList or says undefined when I console.log res.data.fullName etc...

```
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


const FriendsList = () => {

    const [allFriends, setAllFriends] = useState([]);

    console.log(allFriends)
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Text>Friends:</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={allFriends}
                keyExtractor={(friend, id)=> id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return ( 
                        <View>   
                        <Text>{item.fullName }</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default FriendsList
```

Comment: why is there a JSON.stringify of res.data before assigning it to allFriends?

Comment: I took it off and still the same result.  I put it there just to see if it would fix the issue

Comment: What do you get when you log res?

Comment: Also, welcome to stack overflow, please copy/paste your code in the question from your editor, images are rather tedious to deal with when it comes to debugging code that people might want to try for themselves.

Comment: {"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "data": undefined, "env": {"FormData": null}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/users", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"},

Comment: i posted the complete res as a photo

Comment: figured it out....in the data field,  it needed to be data={allFriends.users}.  and then the data showed on the screen